# Laravel eloquent model not able to find foreign key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here's the relevant models.
App\CourseItem => https://pastebin.com/PbYJAan1
App\CourseItemEvent => https://pastebin.com/RV6FBiac

If you look at App\CourseItem
I must define the foreign key

```
    public function courseitemevent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CourseItemEvent::class, 'courseitem_id');
    }
```

It is ignoring all the tablenames i am defining
Even thought ^ works fine i thought it would be cool to find out why

Comment: Can you show your migrations? I mean database structure?

Comment: CourseItem will be converted to snake case `course_items` for table name and for foreign keys will be `course_item_id`; both based on the class name. If you have custom table names, like 'courseitem' then you need to define the keys as well.

Comment: @user3532758 Yeah i understand. But if i've already defined the table name in the model shouldn't it take my tablename that i've defined and convert it to snake case

Comment: That is a different discussion, probably best had in a Laravel's developer community. As it currently stands, model name is the defining point.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this migration structure.this is how you make a foreign key.

//this is just an example for foreign key.user_id of the user_permission table is referencing the user table id.

public function up()
{

```
    Schema::create('user_permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();   
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');      
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi i'm aware of how to create a foreign key and it is indeed linked correctly. Just that the model relationship is finding the wrong foreign key. Well i guess i shouldn't rely too much on the magic that goes behind and already defined a specific foreign key when i link them up